# ROR: undefined method `authenticate'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, change-password

I want to add 'change password' functionality in my rails application and I study it from here (207.44.138.58/~rorexper/viewtopic.php?t=690&highlight=&sid=16f7417dcbb3cb8960912c8134351fd9)

In my view page I add:-

```
 = form_tag :action => 'update' do
   - flash.each do |key, value|
     %div.TxtRed{:class => "flash #{key}"}= value
   %p
     %label Current password
     %br
     = password_field_tag "user[current_password]", nil
   %p
     %label New password
     %br
     = password_field_tag "user[password]", nil
   %p
     %label Confirm password
     %br
     = password_field_tag "user[password_confirmation]", nil
   %P
     = button_tag "Save", :class => "btn-custom ML10", :type => :submit
```

And in controller:-

```
  def update
    return unless request.post?
    @user = Refinery::User.find_by_id(current_user.id)
    if current_user = Refinery::User.authenticate(@user.username, params[:user][:current_password])

       if (params[:user][:password] == params[:user][:password_confirmation])

          current_user.encrypted_password = crypted_password(params[:user] [:password] ,current_user.salt)

          flash[:notice] = current_user.save ?"Password changed" :"Password not changed"
          redirect_to my_page_path

       else

          flash[:notice] = "Password mismatch"
          @current_password = params[:current_password]

       end

    else

       flash[:notice] = "Wrong password"

    end
 end

 def crypted_password(password, salt)
   string_to_hash = password + "nyros" + salt
   Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(string_to_hash)
 end
```

But it does not work properly and gives an error: 
"undefined method `authenticate' for #"

Answer (score 0):

The authenticate method will raise an exception if the object it is called from is nil. In other words, when `find_by` did not find a matching user.

Test that @user is not nil in the condition of an `if` structure, rather than calling the authenticate method in the if condition. So change:

```
@user = Refinery::User.find_by_id(current_user.id)
if !@user.nil?
    current_user = Refinery::User.authenticate(@user.username, params[:user][:current_password])
.
.
.
```

to

```
@user = Refinery::User.find_by_id(current_user.id)
current_user = Refinery::User.authenticate(@user.username, params[:user][:current_password])
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the error he's getting. `authenticate` will still be undefined.